# C# Chaining params function calls

Tags: c#, wrapper, parameters

Is it possible in C# to accept a `params` argument, then pass it as `params` list to another function?  As it stands, the function below will pass `args` as a single argument that is an array of type `object`, if I'm not mistaken.  The goal here is self evident.

```
//ScriptEngine
public object[] Call(string fnName, params object[] args)
{
    try{
        return lua.GetFunction(fnName).Call(args);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Util.Log(LogManager.LogLevel.Error, "Call to Lua failed: "+ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `lua.GetFunction(fnName).Call(args);` is a call to outside of my code, it accepts `param object[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the signature of the `Call` method you're calling accepts a `params object[] args` then you *are* mistaken.  It doesn't consider `args` a single object of thpe `object`, to be wrapped in another array.  It considers it the entire argument list, which is what you want.  It'll work just fine exactly as it stands.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you.  So `params` explodes a given array by its first dimension to fill the arguments?

Comment: @selkathguy No not quite.  If the type provided matches exactly, it passes it exactly.  If it doesn't, and it can treat the parameter as just one item, it wraps it in an array.  If it can't do either, then it won't compile.  If the type provided doesn't match the array type *exactly* then it won't treat it as the entire array, but one object in it.

Comment: So passing a single array of 5 objects to a function like `fn(object a, object b, params object[] c)` would file one into each of `a` and `b`, then the rest would be eaten by c?

Comment: @selkathguy No.  That would not compile.  You would need to pass two objects and an array, or two objects and any number of additional objects.  Unlike some other languages, you cannot pass an array as the argument list for any arbitrary function (without using reflection).

Comment: perhaps you can assist me with the specifics of this question on another posting. Many thanks if you can!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817831/passing-arbitrary-arguments-from-c-sharp-to-lua-functions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.In your case  `args` actualy an array of objects.Your `Call` method should take `params object[]` or just an array of objects as parameter.

You don't need to pass more than one argument to `params`.You can pass an array directly.For example this is completely valid:

```
public void SomeMethod(params int[] args) { ... }

SomeMethod(new [] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to pass the array to another function:

```
void Main()
{   
    int[] input = new int[] {1,2,3};
    first(input); //Prints 3
}

public void first(params int[] args)
{
    second(args);
}

public void second(params int[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
}
```