# Passing Arbitrary Arguments From C# to Lua Functions

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

**I have discovered the cause of the issue.  An answer has been posted below.**

---

EDIT: The problem has changed, please see **"The problem"** section.

I am using LuaInterface.  The generic call for lua functions using this library has this signature `LuaFunction.Call(params object[] args)`.  I have created a wrapper function that catches exceptions from the library and formats them for display on the in-game console window.

I am trying to call a lua function, but it is not receiving the arguments.  This is the line in C#

```
Game.Instance.scriptEngine.Call("GenerateChunk", chunks[chunkID], GetChunkGridPosition(chunkID));
```

Which is simply wrapping a call to this Lua function that accepts two arguments:

```
//lua
function GenerateChunk(worldChunk, chunkGridPosition)
    Log(LogLevel.Error, worldChunk.ToString());
    Log(LogLevel.Error, chunkGridPosition.ToString());
end
```

that merely calls back into a C# `Log` function (which resolves correctly, and is visible in the Lua context).

**The problem** is that I am getting an `"invalid arguments to method call"` error from luainterface when attempting to call the `GenerateChunk` function, throwing this back:

---

```
invalid arguments to method call
   at JASG.ScriptEngine.LuaError(Exception ex) Scripting\ScriptEngine.cs:line 144
   at JASG.ScriptEngine.Call(String fnName, Object[] args) Scripting\ScriptEngine.cs:line 86
   at JASG.ChunkManager.WakeChunk(Int32 chunkID) World\ChunkManager.cs:line 123
   at JASG.ChunkManager.GetChunk(Int32 chunkID, Boolean wakeIfAsleep) World\ChunkManager.cs:line 53
```

---

I have tried various ways of calling the `ScriptEngine.Call` method, tried wrapping the arguments in an object[] array, etc., but no dice.  Any ideas why lua is not receiving my arguments that I am passing?  I have verified both arguments are non-null in C# when being passed in.

Comment: You've verified that your call function has the correct contents of args before the lua call that seems to have nil for the arguments it got passed in? Not just that the function that calls your `call` function has values for `chunks[chunkID]` and `GetChunkGridPosition(chunkID)`?

Comment: @Etan I have appended to the original post.  Yes, it is a non-null array being passed in.  However I am not sure if `object[]` is an acceptable input to `params object[]` or whether it is correctly exploding the arguments.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have edited my post again.  My lua needed colons (of course) instead of periods to access functions.  However, it is still giving me an (albeit different) error about the arguments.

Comment: I am not a C# person but [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/06/10439573.aspx) would seem to indicate that passing args like that should work. I'm not sure what's wrong at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I incorrectly identified the problem as being with the call into Lua.  The error message I was receiving was in fact originating from the Lua script calling back into my C# `Log` function.

I have discovered the hard way that in spite of exposing the enum `LogManager.LogLevel` to the lua script envronment, **Lua does not support enum types**.  Thus,

```
Log(LogLevel.Debug, "hello");
```

was becoming

```
Log("Debug", "hello");
```

when marshalled by LuaInterface for the C# function.  It was not until I created an ancillary `ScriptLog(string level, string msg)` that I was able to properly use the function from within lua.  I wanted to keep the functionality of being able to use the enum names within Lua.

**NOTE**: As Lua does not support enum types, `tonumber(LogLevel.Debug)` fails as well.

Comment: **"Lua does not support enum types."** Lua doesn't support *any* C# types. Period. They are all marshaled into Lua either by converting to a Lua type (such as string or number) or as userdata. In this case, you could easily expose the LogLevels to Lua (as userdata) in such a way that they can be passed to `Log(LogLevel level, ...)`. But you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Lua before, but I've seen this kind of strange behaviors with calling COM objects (or any interop), or when the target assembly call is loaded on a different App Domain, or any other technology that intercommunicates a .Net assembly with a non-.Net one.

Have you tried using the [Serializable] attribute on the classes that define the result of "chunks[chunkID]" and "GetChunkGridPosition(chunkID)"? Are all your interop classes and types compatible between both assemblies?

Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: LuaInterface itself is a library written in C# so it definitely sits on .NET and the CLR.  Not sure if that makes a difference.  I tried making them Serializable anyway, but no luck.  Plus I would rather pass references if at all possible rather than move chunks of data.  These are relatively performance intensive operations I'm doing.

Comment: If this is happening specifically in only one of your Lua methods, but all others seem to work fine, then it has to be a Type conversion issue.

For example, you might be passing a "MyChunk" object, but the Lua code is expecting a "LuaChunk" object. Whichever binding-engine is running in between the caller and callee, it's not being able to deal with the types and it might be defaulting the value to "null".

Can you try passing a very simple object type (for example, an "int" or "string") and see if the GenerateChunk() logs correctly the values?

Answer (score 0):

**Side note:** you should reduce your code to the [shortest example that produces the problem](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#volume). For instance, we don't need to see your wrapper function. You should have tried removing it. If that solved the problem, it's an important clue you should have been mentioned. If the problem remained, then that code is just a distracting irrelevancy for anyone reading this.

Your problem could be in your `Log` function. Everything thing else looks fine, that's the only code we can't actually see, and your problem can be reproduced like this:

```
public static void Log(int errorLevel, string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}

public void Test()
{
    var lua = new Lua();
    lua.RegisterFunction("Log", this, GetType().GetMethod("Log"));
    lua.DoString("function foo() Log('a','b') end");
    lua.GetFunction("foo").Call();
}
```

In this case, because 'a' cannot be marshaled into a number.

Comment: I have discovered the problem and have posted an answer.  Since your answer set me on the path to a resolution, I have upvoted it.

Comment: "set me on the path"? \*lol\* I identified the problem exactly: you were passing invalid arguments to Log. That's where "invalid arguments to method call" was coming from, and it had nothing to do with `Call`, your object array, or anything else.